# Making a class and using awt.point

Tags: java, class, methods

I am trying to write a class Robot that simulates a robot wandering on an infinite plane. The robot is located at a point with integer coordinates and faces north, east, south, or west. I need to supply methods public void turnLeft(), public void turnRight(), public void move(), public Point getLocation(), public String getDirection()
Here is what I have:

```
import java.awt.Point;

public class Robot 
{
public static void main (String [] args){

    Point location;
    char direction;


    public Robot()
    {
        location = new Point();
     char direction = 'N';
    }

    public void turnLeft()
    {

       char direction = 'S';
    }

    public void turnRight()
    {
       char direction = 'E';
    }

    public void move()
    {
        switch(direction)
        {
            case turnLeft():
            {

                break;
            }

            case turnRight():
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public Point getLocation()
    {
        return location;
    }

    public String getDirection()
    {
        return direction;
    }
}
}
```

However I know I'm doing something wrong with the move method .

Comment: The code wouldn't even compile. So, start by compiling it, reading all the errors you get,reading your text book about classes and methods, and fix the errors. Basically everything is wrong in this code. You're declaring constructors and methods inside other methods, you don't understand the differentce between local variables, fields and arguments. This is much too broad. Don't write so much code without even trying to compile. Write something really minimal, compile, test. Then add a tiny little bit, compile, and test. Repeat.

Comment: `case` statements have to be compile-time constants. Method invocations aren't compile-time constants.

Comment: And what makes you think you're doing something wrong?  (Please don't answer with another comment, but with an [edit] to your question.)

Answer (score 0):

1. The methods `turnLeft()` and `turnRight()` have a return type of `void` (which means it does not return anything) so you definitely can't use them in your switch-case-expression. You have to put a value behind a case and a void is definitely none.
2. Case only accepts static values like `'a'`, `"hello world"`, `3`, `4.0f` or constants that are defined with the `static` keyword. (When you want to use non-static values use if)
3. As far as I can see you defined the constructor, class members and methods that belong inside class body inside the main method.

And: Think about what you want to do.
Do you really want to check for the result of a function or do you want to check for every possible direction (`'N'`,`'S'`,`'E'`,`'W'`)? If so you have to to switch over them. (I also recommend defining them like `public static char N='N'` etc.; this will prevent you from typing an invalid direction because your IDE will point out the mistake. Even better is using an `enum`)

I don't want to sound rude but You seem like you don't know a lot about java so I recommend you to actually learn at least some basics of this language.